# JavaFx Label - how to force a new line when displaying data from sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, javafx, label, newline

I understand that in JavaFX we can force a new line in a Label by a code like this:

```
label.setText("Line one \n Line two");
```

My issue is this:

I want to display some poetry from an SQLite database. So I tried having the text like this in the database:

```
 Roses are red \n violets are blue
```

Unfortunately, when I run the program, it simply displays the text including the \n and does not force a new line.

Could tell me how I make it work?

Comment: Is the `\n` explicitly like that in the database? If so, what you really read in was `\\n`.

Comment: @Slaw, yes, it's explicitly like that. I tried typing \\n like you suggested. Unfortunately, the problem still persists. It simply outputs it as \\n rather than creating a new line. I'm scratching my head why it's the case. \n works fine when I use it in the program. It doesn't seem to work only when it's in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have used `\n` in your DB rows. E.g. the following code works without the need of special handling of line breaks:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:poetryDB.db";
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
        s.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS poem(text TEXT NOT NULL)");
    }
    // insert poem containing newline
    try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO poem (text) VALUES (?)")) {
        ps.setString(1, "Roses are red \n violets are blue");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    // print content of the db table
    try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT text FROM POEM");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1).replace("\\n", "\n"));
            System.out.println("----------------");
        }
    }
}
```

If you indeed want to store newlines as `\n` in the db, you need to replace `\n` with newlines after retrieving the data from the db:

```
String value = resultSet.getString(index).replace("\\n", "\n");
```

If you want to fix the db however, all you need to do is run a update that replaces the occurances of `\n`:

```
try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
    s.executeUpdate("UPDATE poem SET text = REPLACE(text, '\\n', '\n')");
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much! I'm so glad you took the time to type out that clear answer. I prefer storing the new lines as \n in the db because the data is typed by someone and I have to display it. So your method of typing it as \n in the db and replacing \\n to \n works like a charm. Thank you. :D